# (Hopefully) one last loop in my hangman game,

Tags: c

I apologize for bugging this forum with my constant Hangman problems. Im hopefully done with this soon. Really been working hard on this. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 20
#define MAX_TRIES 6
char* GetWordFromFile();
int HideWord(char* randomWordfromFile);
void PlayAgain();
void GameLogic(char *randomWordfromFile);
void clear_stdin();
void PlayGame();

int main()
{
printf("Welcome to Hangman. Would you like play? Please answer Y/N. \n");
int PlayorNot = getchar();
if (PlayorNot == 'Y' || PlayorNot == 'y')
    PlayGame();
else
    system("cls");
    printf("Goodbye");

return 0;
   }

void PlayGame()
 {
     char* word = GetWordFromFile();
     GameLogic(word);
     PlayAgain();
     }





char* GetWordFromFile()
{
FILE* pointertoFile = NULL;
char randomWordfromFile[MAX_WORD_LEN];
int i = 0 , ran = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
pointertoFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Dropbox\\Hangman\\hangman.txt" , "r+");
for(; fgets(randomWordfromFile , MAX_WORD_LEN, pointertoFile) ; i++)
          ;
ran = rand() % i;
rewind(pointertoFile);
for(i = 0 ; i < ran ; i++)
    fgets(randomWordfromFile , MAX_WORD_LEN , pointertoFile);
return randomWordfromFile;
}



void GameLogic(char *randomWordfromFile)
{
    int UserGuess;
    int i, x;
    int WrongGuesses;
    size_t j;
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    char HiddenWord[len];
    for (j = 0; j < len; ++j)
    {
        HiddenWord[i] = "_ ";
    }
    printf("%s", HiddenWord);


    for(i = 0; i < MAX_TRIES; i++ )
    {
       printf("Go ahead and guess a letter\n");
       clear_stdin();
        scanf("%d", &UserGuess);


        for (x = 0; x < len; x++)
        {
            if (randomWordfromFile[x] == UserGuess)
                UserGuess = HiddenWord[x];
            else
                break;
        }
}
    printf("%s", randomWordfromFile);

}




void PlayAgain()
{
   printf("Do you want to play again? Please answer with Yes/No?");
    char PlayAgainAnswer = getchar();
    if (PlayAgainAnswer == 'Y' || PlayAgainAnswer == 'y')
        PlayGame();
    else if (PlayAgainAnswer == 'N"' || PlayAgainAnswer == 'n')
        printf("Thanks for playing");
    else
        printf("Thanks for playing");
}


void clear_stdin()
{
  while( getchar() != '\n' ){;}
}
```

Its finally compiling after what seems like days and days of work and debugging. For some reason when I run its printing out letters it should not be. I believe it enters the first loop asking whether the user wants to play. After answering yes, It asks you to guess a letter. But before asking that it should be showing _ _ _ or the like depending on the number of letters in the word.

My guess is that the problem is in the following loop:

```
for (j = 0; j < len; ++j)
{
    HiddenWord[i] = "_ ";
}
printf("%s", HiddenWord);
```

I however cant seem to find a problem in this loop at it is a very simple loop.

Comment: This line `size_t len = strlen(word);`. Where is the definition of `word`?

Comment: char* word = GetWordFromFile();

Comment: I guess you want to write `randomWordfromFile` rather than `word` because `word` is not the name of the parameter of your function.

Comment: I changed that but its still not working. For example right now its printing £££

Comment: Your code is quite messy, therefore it is hard to find all possible problems/errors. However, you do not even check, if `fopen` works correctly.

Comment: Sorry. A real beginner here. Anything I can do to make the program read better? I checked that fopen works correctly earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `i` vs `j` as pointed out by asbumste
2. `HiddenWord[j] = '_';` since you are assigning to a char
3. `HiddenWord[len] = '\0'`
   and of course, the array should be 1 character longer

Hope it helps

P.S. you might want something like:

```
HiddenWord[2*j] = '_';
HiddenWord[2*j+1] = ' ';
```

but you get the point :)

Comment: Thank you! This worked wonders. Seems like maybe the fact that " " instead of ' ' ruined my code. lesson learned to be super careful!

Answer (score 2):

You are using j in the loop and i as the index, you want them to be the same

Comment: Oh whoops. that was wrong but it still doesnt fix the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char HiddenWord[len];
```

to

```
char* HiddenWord = (char*)malloc(len);
```

Since you want your array to be of dynamic size, you want to allocate the memory at runtime.
You should also check whether the memory allocation was successful. Have a look at 
http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation and don't forget to free the memory after you are done with it.

Comment: Im not quite sure how to free memory and how dynamic mememory works but I added that to my code. However the error still doesnt quite work. Any ideas?

Comment: At the end of your function add free(HiddenWord) that's all. Glad your problem got sorted out.